# Adding an arrayList to another arrayList in a separate class?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm having some difficulty adding an arrayList of user details to another arrayList which contains details of each user i create.

I have 2 classes: `addUser` and `Database`.

In the `addUser` class i have the following code:

```
        JLabel submitButton = new JLabel("Submit: ");
        contentPane.add(submitButton);
        JButton addUser = new JButton("+ Add User");
        addUser.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            addToArray();
            databaseArray.add(app);
            frame.dispose();}});
        contentPane.add(addUser);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    //arraylist of details for a single applicant
    final ArrayList<String> app = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void addToArray()
    {
        appNumber = appNumberField.getText();
        name = nameField.getText();
        date = dateField.getText();
        fileLoc = fileLocField.getText();
        country = countryRefField.getText();
        app.add(appNumber);
        app.add(name);
        app.add(date);
        app.add(fileLoc);
        app.add(country);
    }
```

in the database class i have the following code:

```
public class Database
{
    public ArrayList<ArrayList> applicants;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Database
     */
    public Database()
    {
        applicants = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    }

    /**
     * adds a new applicant to the database
     */
    public void addApplicant(ArrayList app)
    {
        applicants.add(app);
    }

    public void list()
    {
       int n = applicants.size();
       for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
       System.out.println(applicants.get(i));
    }
}
```

However when i add a user from the `addUser` class it does not appear when i use the list method in the `Database` class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should definitely considerer creating a real class to hold your user details.

Comment: how do you handle `databaseArray.add(app)` ?

Comment: What is "databaseArray"? Where is that code that initialises that, and what is it pointing to?

Comment: sorry, databaseArray was me messing around with the code. Instead i have: database.addApplicant(app);

Comment: Well, then it should work, from what we see here. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ?

Comment: Are you creating two Database classes by mistake? and calling add on one and list on another totally different one?
Agree, we need to see more of the code or a SSCCE, otherwise it's just guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Store {
int appNumber;// = appNumberField.getText();
String name;// = nameField.getText();
int date;// = dateField.getText();
boolean fileLoc;// = fileLocField.getText();
String country;// = countryRefField.getText();

public Store(int appNumbe, String nam, int dat, boolean fileLo,
        String countr) {
    appNumber = appNumbe;
    name = nam;
    date = dat;
    fileLoc = fileLo;
    country = countr;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Store> app = new ArrayList<Store>();
    app.add(new Store(22, "Name", 2, false, "India"));

}
}
```

I think you should try something like this to store data . It will be easy to insert and retrive .